# How can I find a maximum to this equation

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function that I would like to find it's maximum

```
deposit_likelood <- function(a1,a2) { (0.5672 - 0.092 * a1 + 0.0044 * a2^2 }
```

How can I maximize deposit_likelood while `a1 should be between -3 and +3` and
`a2 should be between 0.5 and 0.9` ?

I tried to use the optimize() function:

```
optimize(deposit_likelood, interval=c(-3,3,0.5,0.9), maximum=TRUE)
```

but I got this error :

```
Error in a2^2 : 'a2' is missing
```

Comment: Something that simple you can solve analytically. Differentiation?

Comment: I understand that, but I want to know how to do it with r so I can use such solution and syntax for a more complex issues.Thanks, Ron

Comment: optimize is one-dimensional so a2 gets left behind. See help(optim)

Comment: also, your function definition has a ( and no ). It's not a valid R function as shown.

Comment: What other solution can I use to solve this If optimize is one-dimensional?

Comment: "optim" is a way to maximise multi-dimensional functions. See help(optim)

Comment: Actually something that simple can be solved by inspection. It clearly goes to infinity as a2->Inf and a1->-Inf, so within the bounds it will be max at the min of a1 and the max of a2 which is (-3, 0.9). If your optimiser gives you anything else you know its not worked!

Comment: I read help(optim) but I still don't see a way to use more than one-dimensional.

Comment: The first example in help(optim) is exactly that. Note how it unpacks the function argument x into x1 and x2. One of the later examples is 25 dimensional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was hoping you would work this out for yourself from the hints (because thats usually a better way to learn) but here you go.

Note I've had to change the function because your question didn't have a valid function in it, and also to unpack the arguments:

```
> deposit_likelood = function(a) {a1=a[1];a2=a[2];return (0.5672 - 0.092 * a1 + 0.0044 * a2^2) }
```

We give `optim` a start point (somewhere in your box constraints), tell it to use the method with box constraints, and specify the constraints:

```
> optim(c(0,.7),deposit_likelood,method="L-BFGS-B",lower=c(-3,.5), upper=c(3,.9), control=list(fnscale=-1))
$par
[1] -3.0  0.9

$value
[1] 0.846764

$counts
function gradient 
       7        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: NORM OF PROJECTED GRADIENT <= PGTOL"
```

The return value has `$par` as the values of `a1` and `a2` respectively. The `$convergence` code zero tells you it worked okay.

Comment: Thank you very much, Spacedman .Your detailed and elegant answer really gave me good starting point